# Taking a picture through camera using Intent and saving it in the database in android

Tags: android

I have created an activity that starts camera intent to take pictures. it run normally and takes pictures but the problem is that I am not been able to store it in the database. Any suggestions or some code. thanks in advance.

Comment: suggestion ? try something before asking.

Comment: there are plenty of such things in web ... search and use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to take your picture.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"image.jpg");
        Uri inputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        System.out.println("outputFileUri in camera===>"+inputFileUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, inputFileUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And in on activity result use its uri.

```
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
          Uri outputFileUri=data.getData();
          //here by using uri you can also saves image to sd card.
     }
```